# Generating JSON dynamically with Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, json, beautifulsoup

I am currently working on a project and I need to scrape data from a website  and generate JSON files with that data.The data specifically is question and its 4 options. Each question with its options have to be collected in a single JSON document. I have written the python code to scrape the individual components but now I am having problem to dynamically make JSON files with them. Is there a way of making JSON documents from python. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for [`json`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) library.

Example:

```
>>> import json
>>> json.dumps([1,2,3,{'4': 5, '6': 7}], separators=(',',':'))
'[1,2,3,{"4":5,"6":7}]'
```

Comment: Is it possible to add the key-value pairs in sequence using json.dumps()